# MS ACCESS How to Replace() HTML Entities?

Tags: ms-access, replace, html-entities

This should be very simple but MS Access is killing me!

All I want to do is find and replace all instances of ' (and some others) with the appropriate character, in this case, an apostrophe.

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Title = Replace(Title, "&#039;", "'")
WHERE Title LIKE '*&#039*'
```

And even a simple select doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Title LIKE '*&#039*'
```

Does anyone have a solution? I really have searched and found nothing for this particular issue.

I could do a PHP script but all this stuff is supposed to be kept in the DB so I kinda need to sort it with a simple query if possible.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Some Sample Data of Title in Table1

```
Row 1. &#039;Quick Release&#039; Loop, Stainless Steel
Row 2. Silver &#039;V&#039; Shaped Edging
Row 3. Plastic &#039;T&#039; Shaped Seal
```

Comment: show us some sample data

Comment: There you go 4dmonster - nothing grand, just simple text titles with html entities in them... I'm only looking to remove simple ones like apostrophes etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad thing is that `#` is system character in jetSQL. There are several ways to deal with it:

1. omit `WHERE` part and update all strings with `replace`.
2. use such `WHERE (InStr(1,[Title],"&#039")>0);`
3. use DAO or ADO recordset

Comment: Option #2 is perfect. My tables are way too big to use option 1 which was the only purpose of the conditioning - so a big big thank you!

Comment: cc: @Chuckun - Good call re: the hash character. I just tried `... WHERE Title LIKE '*&[#]039*'` and that seems to work, too.

Comment: Good to know Gord! Thanks for that :)